# Support both GCC and clang for clang attribute extensions without macros

Tags: gcc, clang

There are lots of extensions beyond C++ standard in clang `__attrbute__`. For example, https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html

I like this kind of extension, but I don't want to give up GCC. One solution is to use macros as follows:

```
#if defined(__clang__)
#define CLANG_ATTRIBUTE_(x) __attribute__((x))
#else
#define CLANG_ATTRIBUTE_(x)
#endif
#define CAPABILITY(x) CLANG_ATTRIBUTE_(capability(x))
// ... ...
```

Then, both GCC and clang are supported for the following piece of code:

```
class CAPABILITY("mutex") mutex
{
    // ... ...
};
```

However, in AUTOSAR (https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/18-10/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf), this kind of macro is not recommended. I'm wondering if there is any alternation to avoid macros used in the source file.

An idea is to annotate the `__attribute__` extensions with C-style comments and use a script to remove the comments as preprocessing before compiling with clang.

```
class /*TAG_REMOVE_COMMENT_BEGIN CAPABILITY("mutex") TAG_REMOVE_COMMENT_END*/ mutex
{
};
```

But this method is not elegant because it has to revise the source code in place and then revert back when the compilation finishes. My question is:

- Is there any feature supported by clang toolkits that can do this kind of things?
- If not, are there any other ways that are more elegant?

Comment: So you invent your own macro processor and add it to the toolchain to sidestep the guidelines? Neat, but if I were you I'd worry about my continued employment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `C++17` or later, [`[[clang::capability(mutex)]]` should work](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) - for C++11/14 it is compiler-dependent on whether unknown attributes are ignored.

Otherwise, justify to your PL/PM/whatever a special exception for this case.

Comment: Good to know the nice solutions in C++17. Unfortunately, the AUTOSAR rules we followed don't upgrade to C++17 yet. So it may not happen in a short time.